# A bug in words counter application

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created [this application](http://jsfiddle.net/54v67r36/). The program counts the number of the words in the text.

But I have bug when I print first character (any character) it taken as a word, I can't understand why.

Here is jQuery:

```
counter = function () {
        var value = $('#text').val();

        if (value.length == 0) {
            $('#wordCount').html(0);
            $('#totalChars').html(0);
            $('#charCount').html(0);
            $('#charCountNoSpace').html(0);
            return;
        }
        //var regex1 = /[^A-Za-z_]/gim;
        var regex1 = /[^a-z_]/gim;
        var regex2 = /\s+/gi;
        var textTrimmed = value.replace(regex1, '');
        var wordCount = textTrimmed.trim().replace(regex2, ' ').split(' ').length;

        var totalChars = value.length;
        var charCount = value.trim().length;
        var charCountNoSpace = value.replace(regex1, '').length;

        $('#textFiltered').html(textTrimmed.trim().replace(regex2, ' '));
        $('#textTrimmed').html(textTrimmed);
        $('#wordCount').html(wordCount);
        $('#totalChars').html(totalChars);
        $('#charCount').html(charCount);
        $('#charCountNoSpace').html(charCountNoSpace);
    };

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#count').click(counter);
        $('#text').change(counter);
        $('#text').keydown(counter);
        $('#text').keypress(counter);
        $('#text').keyup(counter);
        $('#text').blur(counter);
        $('#text').focus(counter);
    });
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Copy &amp; Paste, Word &amp; Character counter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="border">
        <textarea id='text'></textarea>
    </div>
    <button id="count">Count</button>
    <div id="result">
        
        Words: <span id="wordCount">0</span><br/>
        Total Characters(including trails): <span id="totalChars">0</span><br/>
        Characters (excluding trails): <span id="charCount">0</span><br/>
        Characters (excluding all spaces): <span id="charCountNoSpace">0</span>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

How can I fix the bug?

Comment: Can't understand your issue exactly, can you please reframe? What I felt is that no matter how many words I am entering, it shows 1 word only.

Comment: Above issue was as the regex were not in quotes (should be var regex1 = '/[^a-z_]/gim';) - But I think your issue is sth else.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear but from what I understand I think the problem is in the below line

```
var wordCount = textTrimmed.trim().replace(regex2, ' ').split(' ').length;
```

change it to this

```
var wordCount = value.trim().split(' ').length;
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/niranjan_borawake/54v67r36/1/)

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is that you don't want any character to be counted as a word till it's completed, then you can check for existence of ' ' before displaying it as count

Add this line of code to after initializing wordCount variable

```
if (textTrimmed.replace(regex2, ' ').indexOf(' ') < 0)
    wordCount = 0;
```

Refer: http://jsfiddle.net/54v67r36/

Apart from this, your fiddle wasn't counting as the regex expressions were not in quotes (refer my comments) - although your actual counter wasn't having this issue